# Only ROWs with the MAX count

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I am trying to get only the `OBJECT_FK` with the highest count from a temp table.

Here is the **final** result I want:

| OBJECT_FK |
| --- |
| 1006571 |
| 1007025 |

Here my starting data:

| OBJECT_FK |
| --- |
| 1006571 |
| 1006571 |
| 1006571 |
| 1006657 |
| 1006859 |
| 1006859 |
| 1007025 |
| 1007025 |
| 1007025 |
| 1009061 |
| 1009072 |
| 1009072 |
| 1009074 |
| 1009074 |

When I try

```
SELECT   OBJECT_FK, COUNT(OBJECT_FK) totalCount
FROM     #TempTable  
GROUP BY OBJECT_FK
```

I get result but while I am so close I can't seem to refine this into the final result needed.

| OBJECT_FK | totalCount |
| --- | --- |
| 1006571 | 3 |
| 1006657 | 1 |
| 1006859 | 2 |
| 1007025 | 3 |
| 1009061 | 1 |
| 1009072 | 2 |
| 1009074 | 2 |

But if I try to filter the set I run into the following problem:

Using

```
totalCount = MAX(totalCount)
```

I get an error

> Invalid column name 'totalCount'

```
HAVING totalCount = MAX(totalCount)
```

results in

> Invalid column name 'totalCount'

So I tried a different approach and many variants of this

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT  OBJECT_FK, COUNT(OBJECT_FK) AS totalCount
     FROM    #TempProductsWithAnyCharacterics 
     GROUP   BY OBJECT_FK) s
GROUP   BY OBJECT_FK, totalCount
HAVING totalCount = MAX(totalCount)
```

But the result stays the same ....

| OBJECT_FK | totalCount |
| --- | --- |
| 1006571 | 3 |
| 1006657 | 1 |
| 1006859 | 2 |
| 1007025 | 3 |
| 1009061 | 1 |
| 1009072 | 2 |
| 1009074 | 2 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select top 1 with ties OBJECT_FK, COUNT(*) AS totalCount
FROM #TempTable
GROUP BY OBJECT_FK
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: Related ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN#syntax

Comment: Hmm i dont really understand it but it is working for different scenarios i tried 1,2,3 ocurrance Thank you ill have to dig into this so ill understand it

Comment: Group and count, then sort so most frequent OBJECT_FKs come on top (`order by 2 desc`), then with `top 1 with ties` get all the rows from the top where count(*) is the same (this is why I've used `with ties`). See Mark's link for detailed info.